# Regex search in text editors UltraEdit or Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, ultraedit

I would like to find the above code and replace with my own code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
```

The regular expression I've tried is:

```
\<!.*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n].*[\r\n]\<\/head\>
```

It works when I verified it by the online regex tool.

However, it doesn't work with either [UltraEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit) (Perl regex search mode)/[Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) (regex search mode).

Are there are some simplified/ more efficient and working solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Use this regular expression (with *Regular Expression Engine* in the UltraEdit **Find** dialog set to *Perl*):

```
<![\s\S]*</head>
```

Tested with UltraEdit 16.1. But I think it will work for at least UltraEdit 14 and later.

---

Ref: *[Is it possible to match a pattern using a regular expression across a newline in UltraEdit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493557/is-it-possible-to-match-a-pattern-using-a-regular-expression-across-a-newline-in)*

Answer (score 0):

[grepWin](http://code.google.com/p/grepwin/) can help you.

> grepWin is a simple search and replace
>   tool which can use regular expressions
>   to do its job. This allows to do much
>   more powerful searches and replaces.

[image]

grepWin is free and open source.